# 2 dim histogram binning in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, multidimensional-array, indexing, histogram

I have written the following Matlab code that works. It takes two sets of measurements of the different dimension for the same points and builds "rectangle" histograms from it. My goal is to get the array `res`, where `res(i,j1,j2)` = the number of measurements for point i in both bin j1 for the first histogram and bin j2 in the second histogram. Voyez plutot:

```
clear all

nb = 500;
dim1 = 50;
dim2 = 70;
measurement1 = rand(nb,dim1);
measurement2 = rand(nb,dim2);

edges1 = linspace(0,1, 10);
edges2 = linspace(0,1, 6);

res = zeros(nb, length(edges1), length(edges2));

for i = 1:nb
    [N1 EDGES1 BIN1] = histcounts(measurement1(i,:), edges1); 
    [N2 EDGES2 BIN2] = histcounts(measurement2(i,:), edges2); 
    for j1 = 1:length(edges1)-1
       for j2 = 1:length(edges2)-1
           res(i,j1,j2) = sum((BIN1 == j1) & (BIN2 == j2));
       end
    end
end
```

It is totally unsexy, especially the triple for the loop. Could anyone suggest a better way of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried to achieve a nicer solution? Are you sure you need a faster solution?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work in MATLAB 2015b because `BIN1` and `BIN2` are different sizes.